# Upload image in magento frontend

Tags: magento

I need to upload image in customer/account/edit/
I added new attribute, rewritten blocks, helpers, AccountController and added uploading script to editPostAction but unfortunately have not got result, all this changes only created uploading button in customer/account/edit/ page and new attribute in database, but when I choose the file, it's not uploading it to the right directory. Maybe I missed something or doing something wrong.
Maybe someone know some another way how to handle this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to download a file using the Submit form, you need to change the enctype attribute of the 'form' tag. It attribute, in this case, should be "multipart/form-data".

This is a standard demand for submitting files via the form. 
For the standard template the solution is:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/editPost') ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-validate" autocomplete="off">
```

P.S. If you are using some other method of transmitting files to the server, please let us know.